# For vibrations in continuous beam, what is the unit of eigenvalue?

Tags: units, simulations, eigenvalue, vibrations, unit-conversion

I have been solving a fourth order euler bernoulli differential equation to solve for vibrations of a continuous cantilever beam. When I verified for them using Comsol eigenvalue solver, it gives me solutions in unit "rad/s" and as per various books (for eg: SS Rao, WT Thomson) the units for eigenvalue (beta) comes out to be (rad)^0.5/m .
Please explain why there is this difference of units in simulator and conventional analytic solutions.

Comment: I think it would really help if you provide your equation and that of one of the references.  It's not fair to expect us to simply know.  I am familiar with modeling just this system.  It is possible that in one case a sat of scaled coordinates were used, this would change the units on the eigenvalue.  Rad is essentially unit-less and it looks like the diff is between an effective frequency in one case and wavenumber in the other.  Again, post the equations and you might get more help.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of Euler Bernoulli beam is in the form of the following:

$$ \omega_n = (\beta_n L)^2 \sqrt{ \frac{E I}{\rho A L^4} } $$

Considering SI units, $E$ has units of $N/m^2$, $I$ has units of $m^4$, $\rho$ has units of $kg/m^3$, $A$ has units of $m^2$ and $L$ has units of $m$.

Coming to your question, the given values are in the form of $\beta_n$ which has units of $\sqrt{rad}/m$.

$$ \omega_n = (\sqrt{rad}/m \cdot m)^2 \sqrt{\frac{N/m^2 \cdot m^4}{kg/m^3 \cdot m^2 \cdot m^4}} $$

$$ \omega_n = rad \sqrt{\frac{kg-m/s^2 \cdot m^2}{kg \cdot m^3}} $$

$$ \omega_n = rad \sqrt{\frac{1}{s^2}}  $$

Finally you have units of $rad/s$ which is the unit of circular frequency.